# devexpress gridcontrol lookupedit repository item disappears

Tags: devexpress, repositorylookupedit

I have the following:

- an unbound gridcolumn, UnboundType set to String
- this column has a lookupedit repository item
- for this repository item I set via code the displaymember and valuemember properties and the datasource
- I set the Fieldname of this column too
- the Fieldname, displaymember and valuemember are exact the same

But if I run the app and select an entry, then click away, the entry in this column disappears.

Yes, I have googled and found this issue too, but I think, I have set all the things right to get the right result, or not?

Can somebody point out, what can be the problem?

Comment: Can you post some relevant code?  By just what you described, this should work fine.

Comment: Read this article [How to create and populate an unbound column](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E3354)